# Best way to inject a module.factory into another module in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I'm creating my first module and i don't know how to inject a simple object factory.

```
angular.module('mymodule', [])
.factory('mymodulefactory', function () {
    return { a:1, b:2 };
});
```

This is my app:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['mymodule'])
.controller('myController', function($scope, mymodule){ //error
    console.log(mymodule) //undefined
    console.log(mymodulefactory) //undefined
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject like this:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, mymodulefactory) {
    ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rm5kc4u1/